# Center Mouse on Window

Tags: c++, msdn

This is daft, I'm trying to move the mouse to the center of the active window. I cant find a method on MSDN that gives me the coords (RECT) relative to the corner of the screen.

::GetClientRect returns 0,0 for the top left.

Is there a method that returns 100, 134 or some such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function?